# How to find the complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: python, arrays, complexity-theory

I tried to find the complexity of this algorithm and am I right to say the complexity is O(N*log(N))

Can someone show me the full working on the complexity of this algorithm?

```
def binary_min(arr):
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr[0]
    else:
        mid = len(arr)//2
        min1 = binary_min(arr[0:mid])
        min2 = binary_min(arr[mid:len(arr)])
        if min1 < min2:
            return min1
        else:
            return min2
```

Answer (score 0):

complexity of dividing by 2 (like binary search) is `log(N)` and it will happend `N` times so the complexity equals to `Nlog(N)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a binary search algorithm, the time complexity would be `O(log n)`, and the best-case time complexity would be `O(1)` where the `mid` index matches the desired value.